# Transcrever SELECT para expressão de consulta LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Como posso reproduzir a *query* a seguir para expressão LINQ?

```
SELECT nome_empresa, 
       Count(funcionarios.id_funcionario) AS qtdfuncionario, 
       Count(id_colaborador)              AS qtdcolaboradores 
FROM   empresas 
       JOIN funcionarios 
         ON funcionarios.id_empresa = empresas.id_empresa 
       LEFT JOIN colaborador 
              ON colaborador.id_funcionario = funcionarios.id_funcionario 
GROUP  BY nome_empresa
```

Este é o que fiz até o momento, mas ainda não consegui o resultado:

```
var resultado = from e in db.empresas
                join f in db.funcionarios on e.id_empresa equals f.id_empresa into eGroup
                from f in eGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join c in db.colaborador on f.id_funcionario equals c.id_funcionario into eGroup2
                from c in eGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new 
                {
                    NomeEmpresa = e.nome_empresa,
                    CountFuncionario = e.funcionarios.Count,
                    Colaboradores = eGroup2.Count(t => t.id_colaborador != null)
                };
```

Comment: Você está usando Entity Framework?

Comment: Sim estou ultilizando

Comment: Seria interessante postar o código que você já fez. Da forma que está, você só está pedindo uma resposta sem apresentar esforco para alcancá-la.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O motivo de eu ter perguntado se você estava utilizando Entity Framework é justamente por causa da abordagem. LINQ não possui suporte a `Include`, que é utilizado para fazer carga antecipada das informações (*Eager Load*) e montar os *joins* da melhor forma possível. Facilita na legibilidade e evita a confusão que possa estar surgindo nesta expressão LINQ que você colocou na pergunta.

Uma alternativa é usar métodos de expressão (*Expression Methods*) ao invés do LINQ propriamente dito. Ficaria assim:

```
var resultado = db.Empresas
                .Include(e => e.Funcionarios)
                .Select(e => new {
                    NomeEmpresa = e.NomeEmpresa, 
                    CountFuncionario = e.Funcionarios.Count(),
                    Colaboradores = e.Funcionarios.SelectMany(f => f.Colaborador).Count()
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda, foi exatamente o que eu precisava!